# How do I assign an index to a date in the order of days?

Tags: r, indexing

I want to give an index to date in the order of days. 
What I mean is

```
date       day
3/4/2016    1
3/7/2016    2
3/7/2016    2
3/11/2016   3
```

When I use the code below,

```
b$day<-as.Date(b$date,"%m/%d/%y")
levels(b$day) <- 1:length(levels(b$day))
b$day <- as.numeric(b$day)
```

it counts the dates that are not even in the data. After some subtraction, what I get is,

```
date       day
3/4/2016    1
3/7/2016    4
3/7/2016    4
3/11/2016   8
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can do this:

```
b <- data.frame(date=c('3/4/2016','3/7/2016','3/7/2016','3/11/2016'),stringsAsFactors=F);
b;
##        date
## 1  3/4/2016
## 2  3/7/2016
## 3  3/7/2016
## 4 3/11/2016
b$day <- as.Date(b$date,'%m/%d/%Y');
b$day <- match(b$day,sort(unique(b$day)));
b;
##        date day
## 1  3/4/2016   1
## 2  3/7/2016   2
## 3  3/7/2016   2
## 4 3/11/2016   3
```